# A nice geometry question involving a triangle.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, contest-math, triangles

> Suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are points on the sides $AB$ and $AC$ respectively of $\triangle ABC$.The perpendiculars to the sides $AB$and $AC$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively meet at $D$, an interior point of $\triangle ABC$. If $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$, prove that $PM = QM$ if and only if $\angle BDP = \angle CDQ$.

I'm hopeless at geometry. All I could do is figure out that $\triangle PDB \sim \triangle QDC$ and that $\square APDQ$ is cyclic. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A simple sketch in Geogebra shows that "=>" doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I'm sorry, what do you mean by "=>"?

Comment: That =>: $PM = QM \Rightarrow \angle BDP = \angle CDQ$.  Moreover: why has $D$ to be an interior point?

Comment: Could you please attach the link of your Geogebra sketch? I'm not familiar with using geogebra.

Comment: @Michael well, it is a condition given in the question that $D$ is an interior point. Probably it wants us to solve for such triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requested picture from Geogebra shows that $\alpha\neq\beta$.
[image]

Comment: So, the question is wrong?

Comment: At least one direction, yes. (Or I made a dumb error ...)

Comment: The latter is not possible. If yes, then I'm making the same dumb error as you. Anyway, thanks!